# How to interpret clock()?

Tags: c++, time, clock

In my C++ program, I measure CPU time by the clock() command. As the code is executed on a cluster of different computers (running all the same OS, but having different hardware configuration, i.e. different CPUs), I am wonderung about measuring actual execution time. Here is my scenario:

As far as I read, clock() gives the amount of CPU clock ticks that passed since a fixed date. I measure the relative duration by calling clock() a second time and building the difference.

Now what defines the internal clock() in C++? If I have CPU A with 1.0 GHz and CPU B with 2.0 GHz and run the same code on them, how many clocks will CPU A and B take to finish? Does the clock() correspond to "work done"? Or is it really a "time"?

Edit: As the CLOCKS_PER_SEC is not set, I cannot use it for convertion of clocks to runtime in seconds. As the manual says, CLOCKS_PER_SEC depends on the hardware/architecture. That means there is a dependency of the clocks on the hardware. So, I really need to know what clock() gives me, without any additional calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `clock()` function *should* return the closest possible
representation of the CPU time used, regardless of the clock
spead of the CPU.  Where the clock speed of the CPU might
intervene (but not necessarily) is in the granularity; more
often, however, the clock's granularity depends on some external
time source.  (In the distant past, it was often based on the
power line frequence, with a granularity of 1/50 or 1/60 of
a second, depending on where you were.)

To get the time in seconds, you divide by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.  Be
aware, however, that both `clock()` and `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` are
integral values, so the division is integral.  You might want to
convert one to `double` before doing the division.  In the past,
`CLOCKS_PER_SEC` also corresponded to the granularity, but
modern systems seem to just choose some large value (Posix
requires 1000000, regardless of the granularity); this means
that successive return values from `clock()` will "jump".

Finally, it's probably worth noting that in VC++, `clock()` is
broken, and returns wall clock time, rather than CPU time.
(This is probably historically conditionned; in the early days,
wall clock time was all that was available, and the people at
Microsoft probably think that there is code which depends on
it.)

Comment: Thanks. This comes close to answering my question. I am more interested in the hardware side of the clock() routine - because my clock() calls give different results on different computers, where they actually should give roughly the same numbers, right? And "The clock() function should return the closest possible representation of the CPU time used, regardless of the clock spead of the CPU" would mean that faster CPUs give smaller clock numbers, right?

Comment: @mad Yes.  The faster the program runs, the smaller the differences between two calls to `clock()` should be.  Supposing, of course, that the difference is large enough to be significant (which depends on the resolution).

Comment: _"in VC++, clock() is broken, and returns wall clock time, rather than CPU time"_ Oh, boy. I didn't know that, but I ought to have guessed...

Answer (score 2):

You can convert clock ticks to real time by dividing the amount with [`CLOCKS_PER_SEC`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/CLOCKS_PER_SEC/).

Note that since C++11 a more appropriate way of measuring elapsed time is by using [`std::steady_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock).

Comment: Careful with your terminology; it's still not "real time", it's CPU time expressed in a familiar unit. Conversely, I believe `std::steady_clock` is a realtime clock (albeit monotonic) and is therefore not a substitute for `clock()`, which does not measure "elapsed time".

Answer (score 0):

From [man clock](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock):

> The value returned is the CPU time used so far as a clock_t; to get
>   the number of seconds used, divide by CLOCKS_PER_SEC. If the processor
>   time used is not available or its value cannot be represented, the
>   function returns the value (clock_t) -1.

Comment: And of course, the implementation of VC++ is broken in this regard, since it returns wall clock time.